# Decimales con coma html5 en todoslos navegadores

Tags: html5

Tengo el código:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" lang="es" placeholder="" {% if form.monto_inc.value %}value="{{ form.monto_inc.value }}"{% endif %} id="monto_inc" name="monto_inc" required>
```

En el navegador **Firefox**, me acepta cuando escribo **1250,25**
En el navegador **Chrome** no me toma la coma, toco la tecla y no pasa nada, sólo me toma **1250.25**

¿Cómo hago para que me acepte la coma como en Firefox?

**Quiero poder escribir los decimales (centavos de un precio) siempre con coma.**

Comment: ¿No te han [respondido ya a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/300117/7123)? Por resumir, a riesgo de ser reiterativo, el comportamiento de un campo input tipo `"number"` lo decide el navegador y no puedes hacer nada desde el código HTML. Para tener mayor control, hazlo tipo `"text"` e incluye en `pattern`  la expresión regular que valide el formato deseado. Esto hará desaparecer, eso sí, los botones de "aumentar/disminuir" cantidad, pero no otra solución. No olvides también validar lo que recibas en el lado servidor, para evitar clientes maliciosos (que no respeten la regexp)

Comment: Muy cierto @abulafia pues me encontraba [leyendo acerca de los atributos de dicho input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step)

Comment: [Lectura relevante](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization.html) (incluye tabla de navegadores, y su comportamiento respecto al punto y la coma, según las preferencias de lenguaje del usuario --nota, no afecta el lenguaje _del documento_--)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Que en todos los navegadores me acepte coma para decimales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300117/que-en-todos-los-navegadores-me-acepte-coma-para-decimales)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algunos plugins de JQuery para lograr eso.

Un ejemplo de ello es: [JQuery Mask Number](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Number-Input-Formatting-Mask-Number/)

```
$('selectorInput').maskNumber();
```

** Recuerda importar JQuery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```